# The meaning of 'feel out of' and 'kick out of'

Tags: meaning, expressions

The below is an example of these expressions.

The parts of the brain called the limbic system, which includes the regions of the brain that give you a rewarding feeling out of taking a risk, a kind of kick out of taking a risk, and an emotion out of taking a risk, are developing more quickly than the part of the brain called the pre-frontal cortex, which inhibits risk taking.

I understood that 'feel out of something' means feel that something is not mine or feel cut off from something. However, in this example, it might have an opposite meaning. Could anybody explain this?

Comment: If you replace 'out' with from as in ..."a rewarding feeling *from* taking a risk", you might better understand that sentence. And "...a kind of *'rewarding sensation'* from taking a risk"

Comment: Another way I might try to explain it would be that, "a rewarding feeling" is what 'comes out' of taking a risk....

Comment: You are misinterpreting the word associations.  Something gives you a rewarding feeling.  That "something" may be the act of taking a risk.  "Feeling out of" is not being used idiomatically in this case -- it's just that "feeling" and "out" happened to end up next to each other.  Likewise with "kick".

Answer (score 2):

You may be thinking of the locutions "to feel out of it" or "to feel out of sorts," both of which mean that you feel unsettled and not quite your usual self.  In the paragraph on the limbic system "out of" means "derived from."  Thus taking a risk gives you an emotional thrill courtesy of your limbic system, which takes pleasure from risk.

Comment: Also, "I get a kick out of playing chess".  Similar construction.  Neither related to the OP's example.